# Magento 2 redirect going back to admin

Tags: magento2, redirect, magento2.1.5, system-config

I have a controller that is executed in the system configuration.  The desired result is that the code is executed and is redirected back to its original page.  When the url keys are active, the page is always redirected back to the admin dashboard rather than the system configuration.  When the keys are off, the redirect works as intended.  How can I do a proper redirect with the keys on?

```
  public function execute()
{
    $this->helper->testConnections();
    $this->_redirect('admin/system_config_edit/edit/section/settings/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
"adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/YOUR_SECTION_NAME"
```

In this case:

```
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/settings/');
```

E.g:

```
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/currency'');
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Unfortunately, there was no change.  I tried both $this->_redirect('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/settings/') and $this->_redirect('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/currency/') with and without the '/' at the end, and I was still redirected back to the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Admin Panel > Marketing > SEO& Search > URL Rewrites.
- Then press the Add URL Rewrite button.
- Choose "Custom" in Create URL Rewrite select box.
- Choose the store view you want the URL Rewrite to be added to in the
  Store field.
- Set the path you want to be redirected in the Request Path field.
- In the Target Path, you correspondingly set the path you want the old
  one to be redirected to
- Choose Permanent(301) in the Redirect Type field
- Enter short information why you add this rewrite in the Description
  text box (optional).